# Who decided to bury Napoleon in the Dome of Invalides?

Tags: napoleon

Who decided to make Napoleon the center of the Dome of Invalides in Paris? What was the church like before Napoleon? It would be interesting if you could clarify the history of the decision.

Comment: Welcome to History SE. Can you try to include some research/references or links that has some background information? It would be interesting if you could clarify the reason why you are asking this question.

Comment: It would also help if you did preliminary research; [Wikipedia has the answer to your question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Invalides) "The dôme was designated to become Napoleon's funeral place in a law dated 10 June 1840. The excavation and erection of the crypt, that heavily modified the interior of the domed church, took twenty years to complete and was finished in 1861.[4][5])"

Comment: I would imagine his Family. Napoleon 3rd ruled France for quite sometime....famously and with great glory in the Crimean War...and then infamously in Mexico and catastrophically against Bismark and the Prussians. Thanks to Hitler though the Capital of Europe still remains Paris. They need to work on their suburbs there though apparently as that's where all the terrorists live...unlike in the USA.

Comment: French government, I suppose. Who else could decide such thing?

Comment: Wikipedia is your friend: "In 1840, Louis Philippe I obtained permission from the British to return Napoleon's remains to France."

Comment: "Obtained permission" meh? Like France was some Satrapy of Little England?

Comment: @Rathony , I has this question after visiting the Dome, reading Napoleon testament, and thinking what the closed Basilica is like.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace , thanks a lot! Embarassing miss of mine.